# PDE Boundary conditions for characteristic solution for when x=0 and t is some constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve $$\frac{dw}{dt}+4\frac{dw}{dx}=0$$

With initial condition $$w(0,t)=Sin(3t)$$

The characteristic equations are:
$$
\frac{dt}{dt}=1,
\frac{dx}{dt}=4,
\frac{dw}{dt}=0$$
The characteristic solutions are:
$$t=t+t_{0},
x=4t+x_{0},
w=w_{0}$$

Given the initial condition, how should I determine the boundary conditions? I have experiences solving for BC when t=0 and x = some constant not the converse.

Here a go.

Applying the boundary conditions the characteristic solutions are:

$$t(x=0)=t+t_{0}$$
$$x=4t$$
$$w=sin(t_{0})=sin(0)$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are looking for the function $w=w(x,t)$, as I understand.
Equations for the characteristics are
$$\frac{dt}{ds}=1,\quad\frac{dx}{ds}=4,$$
then
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=4,$$
which gives you the system of characteristics
$$x-4t=c,$$
where $c\in R$ is a constant. Because $w$ has to be constant along the characteristics, every function
$$w(x,t)=F(x-4t),$$
where $F\in C^1$, is a solution of your equation.
By using a boundary condition we find specific $F$. So, in our case
$$w(0,t)=F(-4t)=sin(3t),$$
by taking $F(y)=sin(-\frac{3y}{4})$ we get wanted.
Then the solution of the equation is given by the formula
$$w(x,t)=sin(-\frac{3}{4}(x-4t)).$$